# Should my application implement a back button?

Tags: android, design-patterns

My application has a defined flow, starting on 1 fragment and always moving to a 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, and final 6th fragment. Due to the nature of the flow, it is common to move back through fragments too.

I don't implement a back button within the app because I remember reading design theory from Google which recommended to never implement a back button because Android devices implement their own back buttons.

I'm still in development and I've tested the app with users, and I've received feedback that I should implement a back button.

My first thought is to reject the feedback because of the theoretical principle I referred to above, but I can't remember enough detail about the principle to be able to find it again, so I wonder whether my memory is inaccurate.

Is this principle correct? Is it against Google design principles to implement a back button?

Comment: I think that you could implement the [Proper Back Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal), on this way you will create a Back Stack and provide a better navigation experience...

Comment: My thinking is: who will use the app? Google or the users? So do the users want (or need) and more users will use your app. Try to follow as most as possible the guides

Comment: That principal seems to be old or wrong, Android framework provides the hamburguer button that turns into a back button for child activities. Even Gmail provides a back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you've read is [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal).

> Your app should not add a Back button to the UI.

That doesn't mean you can't override the `onBackPressed` and add your desired behavior.
This only means you should use the back button provided by Android and not add another button with the same functionality. Still I've seen loads of apps that use the home button, for instance, with the same behavior as the back button.

A simple implementation of this override behaviour is given by google in the above link:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack()
    } else {
        // Otherwise defer to system default behavior.
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

In here they use it to provide back button behaviour to a WebView. The same can be done to navigate through your fragments in the backstack.

Moreover, the users should be the ones to decide about your UX, Google gives you guidelines that have been proven right. Sometimes those guidelines get outdated as phones and UX evolve. So if your users need a back behaviour you should add one.